# Cut standard output C linux

Tags: c, linux, shell

Im running a program in C which calls shell script. The script sometimes shows an error(`SIOCSARP: Invalid argument`)
The error is not really imporant, it occurs when the program tries to add local IP, it is not important here.

Is there a way to cut any output to the shell in linux here?

Shell script code:

```
#!/bin/sh
arp -s $1 $2
```

Running the script:

```
sprintf(script, "/home/add_arp.sh %s %s", tableI[i].IPaddr, tableI[i].MACaddr);
system(script);
```

Thanks

Comment: How you are running the script from C?

Comment: `./myscript 2>&1 > /dev/null` suppresses all output.

Comment: can you be more specific about "cut any output to the shell"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output you're seeing is on standard *error* rather than standard output, you can use:

```
arp -s $1 $2 2>/dev/null
```

This will drop all error output in to the bit bucket. If it's going to standard output and you want to be selective, you can use something like:

```
arp -s $1 $2 | grep -v 'SIOCSARP: Invalid argument'
```

This will remove all lines containing that text.

You can also combine standard output and error to the standard output stream and be selective:

```
arp -s $1 $2 2>&1 | grep -v 'SIOCSARP: Invalid argument'
```

And finally, if you don't want to see *any* output:

```
arp -s $1 $2 &>/dev/null
```

Although I wouldn't use that last one myself unless I was sure I didn't want to know about *any* problems.

Comment: Just the last one is not really working at all, but I am ok with the first one

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
arp -s $1 $2 &> /dev/null
```

will drop any output.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect stderr to /dev/null like this:

```
arp -s $1 $2 2> /dev/null
```